# How can I convert character date time to Date class?

Tags: r

I have some date times that look like this:

```
2021-01-03T13:01:00
```

Currently they are a character string and I want to convert it to a date. I believe that I need to remove the `'T'` that is in the middle of the character string in order to do this.
Thank you!

Comment: `as.POSIXct("2021-01-03T13:01:00", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` or `as.Date("2021-01-03T13:01:00", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")`. See `?strptime` for the `%`-codes.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to convert it do a date (and hence lose the time information), you can use the `as_date()` function from the `lubridate` package. It should work fine.

```
library(lubridate)

string <- "2021-01-03T13:01:00" #sample string

date <- as_date(string) #convert it to date

str(date)
```

output:

```
Date[1:1], format: "2021-01-03"
```

Comment: This is much more a comment; if you want it to be an answer, the least you could do it run your code on the sample data provided in OP (as scant as it is).

Comment: @r2evans - GO NAVY BEAT ARMY I wasn't aware of this. Thank you for for the clarification. I edited my post.